# github-contributions-react package not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling, vite, npm-package

[My error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5udDB.png)

When run my react project then showing this error:
`[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve entry for package "github-contributions-react". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.`

How to solve this error?

I also trying to solved this problem but it's dose not working.
I want to showing my github contributions chart on my portfolio.[vite.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aw9P.png)[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtfEt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.